# Indexed getter only in Dozer

Tags: dozer

I'm struggling with a mapping in Dozer. The basic structure of my classes is this:

```
class Foo {

    private String someString;

    public String getSomeString() {
        return someString;
    }

    public void setSomeString(String someString) {
        this.someString = someString;
    }
}
```

and the interesting part:

```
class Bar {

    // note that no field is declared

    public String[0] getSomeBarString() {
        // This returns an array where the acctually desired string is a index 0
    }

    public void setSomeBarString(String someString) {
        // stores the string otherwise
    }
}
```

Compensating the absence of a field and the differently named getter/setter methods was quite easy:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>Foo</class-a>
    <class-b>Bar</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>someString</a>
        <b get-method="getSomeBarString" set-method="setSomeBarString">someBarString</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

From my understanding I could even omitt `get-method` and `set-method` as there is no field access by default.

My problem is that the getter is indexed and the setter isn't. I've already read about [indexed property mapping](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/indexmapping.html) but it does it both ways. Is there a way to make only one direction indexed? E.g. would `get-method="getSomeBarString[0]"` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a night of sleep I got an idea myself. I just define two one way mappings and make one of them indexed. It also turns out indexing is defined the same way (after the property name) even if you declare a different `get-method` or `set-method`.

```
<mapping type="one-way">
    <class-a>Foo</class-a>
    <class-b>Bar</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>someString</a>
        <b set-method="setSomeBarString">someBarString</b>
    </field>
</mapping>

<mapping type="one-way">
    <class-a>Bar</class-a>
    <class-b>Foo</class-b>
    <field>
        <a get-method="getSomeBarString">someBarString[0]</a>
        <b>someString</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```